# NodeJS http post data empty

Tags: node.js, angular, http-post

I am not able to get the data in the http post method of express nodejs.I am posting data from angular2. When i inspect in the network section of chrome, the payload is visible but the same data is received blank at app.post method.Please help me.

angular2 code

```
  this.headers = new Headers();
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let body = JSON.stringify({name:"Lionel Messi"});



 return this.http
.post('http://localhost:8081/save',body
     ,this.headers);   

}
```

nodejs code

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/save', function (req, res) {
console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");

console.log(req.body);// output - {}
res.send('Hello POST');
})
```

[Network Section in Chrome....payload is proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia45v.png)

Comment: Can you upload some code

Comment: try changing 'Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded' to 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

Comment: have tried that, but does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` method in node.js will not work . You need to use `console.log("Hello");`

Second thing is to get body data , use `req.body.name`

My way of writing code is like below and it works

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/save',
    data: {name:"Lionel Messi"}
})
.success(function(data) {
     return data
  })
.error(function(error) {
     // handle error
});
```

Other way you can try is:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8081/save', {name:"Lionel Messi"})
.then(function(data) {return data})   
.catch(function() {console.log("Error Occured");});
```

Comment: Do you see your both server and client api signature is different. One is /save and other is /api . @user3107338

Comment: Corrected that as well....am extremely sorry for that again. api is same, even data is sent properly from client but nt able to receive at server

Comment: but i dont have any error sending data from client side.....it is sent properly.....m not receiving the same data at server side......  check the image that i have attached.... "Network Section in Chrome....payload is proper"

Comment: Why you used stringify ??@user3107338

Comment: because the body section of post method takes only string as argument.

Comment: It does not accept......Signature of Post method - (method) Http.post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>

Comment: can you try this        let body = 'name=Lionel'

Comment: Try content type as       application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: i changed the code to  "return this.http
  .post('http://localhost:8081/save',body
         ,{headers: headers}); " and it worked........the third parameter syntax had to be changed to refer to local header variable.......thanks for your help though..

Comment: ur suggestion to change the content type helped as well...thank you....marking ur reply as right answer.

Comment: final code....                                                                                                               var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      let body = {name:"Lionel Messi"};
  var params = JSON.stringify(body);
 
  
     return this.http
  .post('http://localhost:8081/save',params
         ,{headers: headers});

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this-
Suppose you have sent username and password from your browser by post method.

```
app.post("/ url,function(request,response)
{ var username=request.body.username;
var password=request.body.password;})
```

Comment: in request.body i get blank

Comment: First of all check that in client side you are sending data correctly or not.

Comment: If you send it perfectly in client side you can easily recieve it on server

Comment: Have attached an image as well where it shows the data, it is exactly the one that i am sending.
click - "Network Section in Chrome....payload is proper"